# Firestore rules unit test throws "Transaction lock timeout." error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, firebase-security, ts-jest

I am setting up my firestore rules unit test environment, But there have some issue, If I initialize `testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment` in every test file(Basically I just test 5 file with same code below), If just only one file it always passes.

```
import {
  assertSucceeds,
  initializeTestEnvironment
} from "@firebase/rules-unit-testing"
import { setDoc,Timestamp, serverTimestamp } from "firebase/firestore";
import { describe, test } from "@jest/globals";
import * as fs from 'fs';

const MY_PROJECT_ID = "projectId";

describe("app", () => {

  test("test1", async () => {

    let testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
      firestore: {
        rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8080
      },
    });

    const user = testEnv.authenticatedContext("PE8T3x91fsOw9YZj4fkiXEdjZNsE", {
      firebase: {
        sign_in_provider: "google.com",
      }
    });
    const reference = user.firestore().collection("profile").doc("user");

    await assertSucceeds(setDoc(reference, {}));

    await testEnv.clearFirestore();
    await testEnv.cleanup();
  });
})
```

And the result:

```
> test@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  test/t1.test.ts
  ● app › profile create

    {"error":{"code":409,"message":"Transaction lock timeout.","status":"ABORTED"}}

      at RulesTestEnvironmentImpl.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/src/impl/test_environment.ts:120:13)
      at step (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:74:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:55:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:45:58)

 FAIL  test/t2.test.ts
  ● app › profile create

    {"error":{"code":409,"message":"Transaction lock timeout.","status":"ABORTED"}}

      at RulesTestEnvironmentImpl.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/src/impl/test_environment.ts:120:13)
      at step (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:74:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:55:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:45:58)

 PASS  test/t3.test.ts (5.1 s)
  ● Console

    console.warn
      [2023-11-12T06:24:03.129Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x4a18711c error. Code: 10 Message: 10 ABORTED: Transaction lock timeout.

      at Logger.defaultLogHandler [as _logHandler] (node_modules/@firebase/logger/src/logger.ts:115:57)
      at Logger.Object.<anonymous>.Logger.warn (node_modules/@firebase/logger/src/logger.ts:206:5)
      at logWarn (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/log.ts:69:15)
      at ClientDuplexStreamImpl.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/platform/node/grpc_connection.ts:302:9)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:705:18)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
      at node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:132:24

 FAIL  test/t4.test.ts (5.112 s)
  ● app › profile create

    {"error":{"code":409,"message":"Transaction lock timeout.","status":"ABORTED"}}

      at RulesTestEnvironmentImpl.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/src/impl/test_environment.ts:120:13)
      at step (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:74:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:55:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@firebase/rules-unit-testing/dist/index.cjs.js:45:58)

 PASS  test/t5.test.ts (5.253 s)
  ● Console

    console.warn
      [2023-11-12T06:24:05.182Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.6.0): GrpcConnection RPC 'Write' stream 0x5bdb727c error. Code: 13 Message: 13 INTERNAL: Can't swap from CLOSED to COMMIT.

      at Logger.defaultLogHandler [as _logHandler] (node_modules/@firebase/logger/src/logger.ts:115:57)
      at Logger.Object.<anonymous>.Logger.warn (node_modules/@firebase/logger/src/logger.ts:206:5)
      at logWarn (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/util/log.ts:69:15)
      at ClientDuplexStreamImpl.<anonymous> (node_modules/@firebase/firestore/src/platform/node/grpc_connection.ts:302:9)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:705:18)
      at Object.onReceiveStatus (node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
      at node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:132:24

A worker process has failed to exit gracefully and has been force exited. This is likely caused by tests leaking due to improper teardown. Try running with --detectOpenHandles to find leaks. Active timers can also cause this, ensure that .unref() was called on them.

Test Suites: 3 failed, 2 passed, 5 total
Tests:       3 failed, 2 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.063 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Also very rare happen the test could be all passed, But in most of time at least 1 would failed.